# Push and pul in css without bootstrap

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

First of all I am trying to understand responsive design WITHOUT bootstrap or any other framework, this is just an exercise to learn. 
I am trying to make a grid and I am trying to adapt the push and pull classes from bootstrap on my own. 
For example there a 3 boxes: box1, box2 and box 3. Now I am trying to change the order when on mobile view (<768px). So I am trying to make an Order like box3, box 2 and box1. Or any other order. How can I do it without bootstrap. 
Here is my attempt.

With this I am trying to change the order on a media query. How can I do this with css?

```
.box-1 {
        left: 8.33%;
    }
    .box-6 {
        right: 50%;
    }
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainContainer {
 width: 1170px;
 padding: 15px;
}
.mainContainer div[class^="box-"] {
 float: left;
}
.box-1 {
 width: 8.33%;
}
.box-2 {
 width: 16.66%;
}
.box-3 {
 width: 25%;
}
.box-4 {
 width: 33.33%;
}
.box-5 {
 width: 41.66%;
}
.box-6 {
 width: 50%;
}
.box-7 {
 width: 58.33%;
}
.box-8 {
 width: 66.66%;
}
.box-9 {
 width: 75%;
}
.box-10 {
 width: 83.33%;
}
.box-11 {
 width: 91.66%;
}
.box-12 {
 width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="box-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
 .box-1 {
  left: 8.33%;
 }
 .box-6 {
  right: 50%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>responsive</title>
<link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
 <div class="box-1">box1</div>
 <div class="box-5">box5</div>
 <div class="box-6">box6</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with flex

```css
@media screen and (max-width:300px){
    .mainContainer{
        display:flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .box-6{order:2;}
    .box-5{order:1;}
    .box-1{order:3;}
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
 <div class="box-1">box1</div>
 <div class="box-5">box5</div>
 <div class="box-6">box6</div>
</div>
```